# Meteor Template re-renders when Accounts.createUser throws error

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js

So basically I have a template and within that template I have a template that renders a form. Attached to the form is a submit event that when triggered, validates the from data and calls Accounts.createUser.

In the case that Accounts.createUser throws an error it, for some unknown reason, causes the upper level template to re-render in turn the second level template re-renders thus removing the values in the form fields and discarding the errors that were inserted below each field using jquery.

If Accounts.createUser doesn't throw an error, everything works fine, user is "logged in" and the inner page is rendered properly..

Is this a bug in Meteor? I don't see why Accounts.createUser throwing an error would cause a template re-render..

Answer (score 1):

1) Check all dependencies for the upper template. Does any of its data depend on `createUser` result? Double-check all `Session` variables.

2) Do you have a callback in the `createUser` call?

3) Try putting your form template within a `{{#constant}}` block. This should prevent rerendering and losing data. Also, if you use `preserveInputs` package, remember that input data is preserved **only** for inputs that have either `id` or `name` set.

Comment: Hey, thank for the response.. Turns out that I just spend the past 12 hours debugging this because I display a loading message by rendering a template that depends on Meteor.loggingIn()

Comment: One would not think that you that you'd be considered logging in when the account creation just errored out..