# Finding cause of template being destroyed/recreated

Tags: javascript, meteor

trying to debug something. On our client, we have a `Accounts.createUser()` call, which include a callback that looks like:

```
function(err) {
  if (err) {
    Session.set('entryError', err.reason);
  }
  else {
    return Router.go('/');
  }
}
```

With this setup, a normal signup (i.e. with no errors) works fine. However, if there's an error, the template is destroyed, created, and rendered, twice. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17849923/meteor-template-re-renders-when-accounts-createuser-throws-error), and went on a hunt for potential reactive variables triggering this. The only thing I can find that changes between the two template destroyed/created/rendered calls is `Meteor.loggingIn()` (including session variables). That doesn't seem to be causing this, because when I removed all references to it and dependencies on it, the problem continued.

Any pointers?

ETA: per the request below.

signUpPage.html:

```
<template name='signUpPage'>
  <main id="signUpPage">
    <h1 class="accountsTitle">Sign Up</h1>
    <p id="signInPrompt">If you already have an account <a href="/sign-in">sign in</a>.</p>
    <form id='signUpForm'>
      {{> entryError}}
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="usernameInput">Username</label>
        <input id="usernameInput" type="string" class="form-control" value=''>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="emailInput">Email Address</label>
        <input id="emailInput" type="email" class="form-control" value=''>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="passwordInput">Password</label>
        <input id="passwordInput" type="password" class="form-control" value=''>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="confirmPasswordInput">Confirm Password</label>
        <input id="confirmPasswordInput" type="password" class="form-control" value=''>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="signupCodeInput">Signup Code</label>
        <input id="signupCodeInput" class="form-control" value=''>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign up</button>
    </form>
  </main>
</template>
```

signUpPage.js

```
Template.signUpPage.events({
  'submit #signUpForm': function(event, template) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Get the input values from the form
    var username = template.find("#usernameInput").value.trim();
    var email = template.find("#emailInput").value.trim();
    var signupCode = template.find("#signupCodeInput").value;
    var password = template.find("#passwordInput").value;
    var confirmPassword = template.find("#confirmPasswordInput").value;

    // Log the signup attempt
    var signupAttempt = {'type':'signup', 'username':username, 'email':email, 'password':password, 'signupCode':signupCode};
    Logins.insert(signupAttempt);

    // Validate username presence
    if (!username.length)
      return Session.set('entryError', 'Username is required');

    // Validate email presence
    if (!email.length)
      return Session.set('entryError', 'Email address is required');

    // Validate password
    var passwordErrors = validatePassword(password, confirmPassword);
    if (passwordErrors.length) {
      var errorsString = passwordErrors.join("\r\n");
      Session.set('entryError', errorsString);
      return;
    }

    // Validate signup code
    if (!signupCode.length)
      return Session.set('entryError', 'Signup code is required');

    Meteor.call('createAccount', username, email, password, signupCode, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        Session.set('entryError', err.reason);
        return;
      }
      else {
        Meteor.loginWithPassword(username, password);
        return Router.go('/');
      }
    });
  }
});

Template.signUpPage.destroyed = function () {
  Session.set("entryError", null);
};

Template.signUpPage.created = function() {
  document.title = "Grove OS | Sign Up";
};
```

The following are js files where `entryError` is used:

```
Template.signInPage.events({
  'click #signInButton': function(evt, template) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    // Making lowercase here, check on the server should be case insensitive though
    var email = template.find('#emailInput').value.trim().toLowerCase();
    var password = template.find('#passwordInput').value;

    if (!email.length)
      return Session.set('entryError', 'Email is blank');

    if (!password.length)
      return Session.set('entryError', 'Password is blank');

    var loginAttempt = {'type':'login', 'email':email, 'date':new Date()};

    return Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, function(error) {
      if (error) {
        loginAttempt.status = 'error';
        Logins.insert(loginAttempt);
        return Session.set('entryError', error.reason);
      } else{
        loginAttempt.status = 'success';
        Logins.insert(loginAttempt);
        return Router.go("/");
      }
    });
  },
  'click #signUpButton': function(evt, template) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    Router.go("signUpRoute");
  },
  'click #forgotPasswordButton': function(evt, template) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    Router.go("forgotPasswordRoute");
  }
});

Template.signInPage.destroyed = function () {
  Session.set("entryError", null);
};

Template.signInPage.created = function() {
  document.title = "Grove OS | Sign In";
};
```

-

```
Template.resetPasswordPage.helpers({
  error: function() {
    return Session.get('entryError');
  }
});

Template.resetPasswordPage.events({
  'submit #resetPasswordForm': function(event, template) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var password = template.find('#passwordInput').value;
    var confirmPassword = template.find('#confirmPasswordInput').value;
    // Validate password
    var passwordErrors = validatePassword(password, confirmPassword);
    if (passwordErrors.length) {
      var errorsString = passwordErrors.join("\r\n");
      return Session.set('entryError', errorsString);
    } else {
      return Accounts.resetPassword(Session.get('resetToken'), password, function(error) {
        if (error) {
          return Session.set('entryError', error.reason || "Unknown error");
        } else {
          Session.set('resetToken', null);
          return Router.go("/");
        }
      });
    }
  }
});


Template.resetPasswordPage.created = function () {
  document.title = "Grove OS | Reset Password";
};
```

-

```
Template.forgotPasswordPage.events({
  'submit #forgotPasswordForm': function(event, template) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var email = template.find("#forgottenEmail").value;
    if (!email.length) {
      return Session.set('entryError', 'Email is required');
    } else {
      return Accounts.forgotPassword({
        email: email
        }, function(error) {
          if (error)
            return Session.set('entryError', error.reason);
          else
            return Router.go("/");
      });
    }
  }
});

Template.forgotPasswordPage.created = function () {
  document.title = "Grove OS | Forgot Password";
};
```

-
Router code (combined from 2 files):

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------
// Global Configuration

Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'appBody',
  notFoundTemplate: 'notFoundPage',
  loadingTemplate: 'loadingPage',
  yieldTemplates: {
    'appHeader': {to: 'header'},
    'appFooter': {to: 'footer'}
  }
});

// Have to sign in to access all application pages
Router.onBeforeAction(function() {
  console.log("Global router onBeforeAction calle");
  // if (!Meteor.loggingIn() && !Meteor.user()) {
  if(!Meteor.user()){
    this.redirect('/sign-in');
  }
  this.next();
}, {
  // whitelist which routes you don't need to be signed in for
  except: [
    'signUpRoute',
    'signInRoute',
    'forgotPasswordRoute',
    'signOutRoute',
    'resetPasswordRoute',
    'pageNotFoundRoute'
  ]
});

// Subscriptions application-wide
Router.waitOn(function() {
  if (Meteor.loggingIn() || Meteor.user())
    return Meteor.subscribe("userGroups");
});

//--------------------------------------------------------------
// Root route

Router.route('landingRoute', {
  path: '/',
  onBeforeAction: function(){
    console.log("other global one is being called");
    // if (!Meteor.loggingIn() && !Meteor.user()){
    if(!Meteor.user()){
      this.redirect('/sign-in');
    }else{
      this.redirect('/grove/dashboard');
    }
    this.next();
  }
});


//--------------------------------------------------------------
// Static Routes

Router.route('/glossary', {
  path: '/glossary',
  template: 'glossaryPage'
});

Router.route('/eula', {
  path: '/eula',
  template: 'eulaPage'
});

Router.route('/privacy', {
  path: '/privacy',
  template: 'privacyPage'
});

Router.route('/about', {
  path: '/about',
  template: 'aboutPage'
});

Router.route("signUpRoute", {
  path: "/sign-up",
  template: "signUpPage"
});

Router.route("signInRoute", {
  path: "/sign-in",
  template: "signInPage"
});

Router.route('signOutRoute', {
  path: '/sign-out',
  template: "signOutPage",
  onBeforeAction: function() {
    Meteor.logout();
    Router.go('/');
    this.next();

  }
});

Router.route("forgotPasswordRoute", {
  path: "/forgot-password",
  template: "forgotPasswordPage",
});

Router.route('resetPasswordRoute', {
  path: 'reset-password/:resetToken',
  template: "resetPasswordPage",
  data: function() {
    Session.set('resetToken', this.params.resetToken);
    return ;
  }
});

Router.route("404Route", {
  path: "/page-not-found",
  template: "notFoundPage",
});

Router.route("dashboardRoute", {
  path: "/dashboard",
  template: "dashboardPage"
});

Router.route('createShrub', {
  path: '/tools/createShrub',
  template: 'upsertShrubPage',
  waitOn: function(){
  },
  data: function () {
  },
});

// TODO figure out how to dynamically render templates
// based on if the slug is a group, user, or nothing
// and also conditionally subscribe
Router.route('profileRoute', {
  path: '/:ownerSlug',
  template: 'myProfilePage'
});

Router.route('groveRoute', {
  path: '/:ownerSlug/:groveSlug',
  template: 'grovePage',
  data: function () {
    return Groves.findOne({ slug: this.params.groveSlug });
  },
});

Router.route('shrubRoute', {
  path: '/:ownerSlug/:groveSlug/:shrubSlug',
  template: 'shrubStaticPage',
  data: function() {
    Session.set("currentShrub", this.params.shrubSlug);
    return ShrubTemplates.findOne({ slug: this.params.shrubSlug });
  },
  action: function() {
    if (this.ready())
      this.render();
    else
      this.render('loadingHolder');
  }
});
```

Comment: Could you post the relevant template HTML+JS, and any JS that uses the `entryError` session variable?

Comment: Sorry to ask for more code, but can you post your route/controller code as well?  I think that's most likely to be the culprit. Ta.

Comment: Added the requested router code

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turned out that as part of the router there was this function:

```
Router.waitOn(function() {
  if (Meteor.loggingIn() || Meteor.user())
    return Meteor.subscribe("userGroups");
});
```

The change in `Meteor.loggingIn()` caused this function to run, which we saw with our loading page getting displayed briefly. We're changed the `if` statement so that it no longer contains the `Meteor.loggingIn()` check. A little embarrassing, really--I swear I looked at that line before. Not sure what happened in my thought process to miss this. At least now I have a better understanding of Iron Router.